# When does a framework stop being a framework?

Tags: frameworks

So I'm trying to classify my application and have run into an issue: What type of program is it?

The shortened version is an pluggable and hookable IRC program. It has Hook management, plugin management (for writing in different languages), a database persistence layer, and a nice GUI. Setup and external access is through a single controller, while plugins have access to everything.

So as more of a general question, when does a framework just stop being a framework?

(As a side note, should this be community wiki?)

Comment: Seriously, who cares? What would you do differently if it was a "Framework" as opposed to if it wasn't? Are you looking for marketing advice, or programming advice? If your market changes, your programming strategy my change, but I don't see the point to this question.

Comment: Well I'm trying to figure out what to call it to keep consistency, and also to label the website that its on.